# Kotlin ArrayList IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following ArrayList in Kotlin:

```
private var myArrayList = arrayListOf<ByteArray>(ByteArray(20), ByteArray(20), ByteArray(20))
```

My understanding of this syntax is that the size of this `ArrayList` is implicitly defined by the amount of elements passed into the constructor; so 3 in this case? Further to this, I should be able to access the nth element of this `ArrayList` using the following syntax: `myArrayList[n]`.

I believe that my understanding of this process is wrong (and I'm not sure which bit). I think this because when I try to set values of the `ArrayList` in either of the following ways:

```
myArrayList[0] = someByteArrayValue
```

OR

```
myArrayList.add(0, someByteArrayValue)
```

I receive the following error:

> `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

Why is the size of `myArrayList` equal to `0`?

At no point do I (intentionally *or* knowingly call `myArrayList.clear()`) so I'm not sure how the size is ever set to `0`.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Did you try like this too? : `myArrayList.add(someByteArrayValue)`

Comment: Please show a complete code sample where the error can be reproduced. Based on the code that you've posted, everything should work with no exceptions.

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån I've not tried in that way as I need the values to be set at specific indexes.

Comment: @yole I am working on that, I can only repro the error within some very involved code (BLE with a ton of callbacks) at the moment.

Comment: Okay, Do you get the error as soon as you add the value or while retrieving the value from the arraylistof?

Comment: The error is as soon as I add the value.

Comment: *I should be able to access the nth element of this ArrayList using the following syntax: myArrayList[n]* no it should be myArrayList[n-1]

Comment: I don't understand, How is such an error possible on adding the element.

Comment: @forpas Could you explain?

Comment: Did you try to give only the capacity. private var myArrayList = arrayListOf<ByteArray>(3)

Comment: If you want to access the 1st element you use myArrayList[0]

Comment: I think you might just be attempting to access that info before the array has been initialized, it happens. I just tried the code you described above and it works just fine.

Comment: `myArrayList ` is a `var` , not a `val` Is it possible that it is later set to another value (e.g. an empty list) ?